# Is there a shortcut to focus to the GitHub Copilot Chat panel in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, github-copilot

I've been extensively using Github Copilot and I'm looking for a convenient keybinding to effortlessly switch between the GitHub Copilot Chat panel and my code editor. I've experimented with various keybinding configurations, but unfortunately, none of them seem to be effective in achieving this task.

Answer (score 3):

[marius-mihail's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77896809/64635) worked for quick chat, but not the chat panel for me (I'm on macOS, not sure if related), so I udated it to toggle between editor and chat panel (opening the later if needed):

```json
    {
        "key": "ctrl+alt+cmd+c",
        "command": "workbench.panel.chat.view.copilot.focus",
        "when": "editorFocus"
    },
    {
        // Move focus back to the Editor
        "key": "ctrl+alt+cmd+c",
        "command": "workbench.action.focusActiveEditorGroup",
        "when": "!editorFocus"
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: I've found a way

Add this to your `keybindings.json` file:

```json
  {
    // Move focus to the GitHub Copilot Chat panel
    "key": "ctrl+0",
    "command": "workbench.panel.chat.view.copilot.focus",
    "when": "!inEditorsPicker && !inQuickOpen"
  },
  {
    // Move focus back to the Editor
    "key": "ctrl+0",
    "command": "workbench.action.focusActiveEditorGroup",
    "when": "inEditorsPicker || inQuickOpen"
  }
```

Comment: fyi: ctrl+0 is the default keybinding for focusing the primary sidebar and whatever view container is currently active in it.